# Monitor a threads Windows Phone Emulator in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, monitoring

In Windows Phone most of methods run `asynchronously` in separate `thread`, when a lot of threads, it is very hard to debug application. How can monitor threads in Windows Phone? Any tool that can give any information about an asynchronous operations.

I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Emulator Windows Phone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> most of methods run asynchronously in separate thread

They don't.

"most of methods" run asynchronously by the CLR thread pool that only has a few threads.

Unless you've created a lot of threads yourself, which is very bad idea - threads are expensive, and CLR thread pool works great.

> How can monitor threads in Windows Phone?

When paused while debugging, VS2010 has "Threads" window.